# Which parts of a where are applied in the Storage engine and which in the MySQL?

Tags: mysql, data-structures, indexing, innodb, b-tree

I have read that the SQL is parsed by MySQL and which interacts with the storage engine e.g InnoDB.
It seems that the following where: `WHERE some_id < 5 AND some_id <> 1` only the `some_id < 5` is passed to the storage engine while the `some_id <> 1` is filtered at the server.
As I have understood this, this is due to the fact that the storage engine api offers a method only to get "something" which is indexed "less than" so as to implement a range search.
But what I can not understand is why doesn't the API also not offer the option to do the range **AND** exclude certain values.
Is this an inherent limitation of the underlying data structure? Can anyone explain this?

Comment: Is this a actual query you are running? The and part of the query will be executed. MySQL will not FILTER a where clause and remove some piece of the query string. I suspect your data does not contain `some_id = 1 `

Comment: @Namphibian:Not `=1` but `<> 1`

Answer (score 0):

I think what you have read is superseded by Index Condition Pushdown introduced with MySQL 5.6: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/index-condition-pushdown-optimization.html

Comment: From your link:`Without ICP, the storage engine traverses the index to locate rows in the base table and returns them to the MySQL server which evaluates the WHERE condition for the rows` So why does the WHERE need to be done in the server?

Comment: @Jim It's the difference between access and filter predicates or sargable and non-sargable predicates: not every `WHERE` condition can be used to access an index. The remaining `WHERE` conditions are then left over to the server (e.g., if the column it filters on is not present in the used index).

Comment: So in my example why the `<> 1` can not be passed to the storage engine?

Comment: @Jim I think in your case it is just because MySQL could not do it prior 5.6.